# Table with vertical text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, cell

I am new here and would need your help. I would love to replicate the following table in Latex.

[image]

I wrote this code.

```
\begin{tabular}{c|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|c}
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Technical/economic systems} \\
  \cline{2-3}
  \multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Internal}} &
  Cell 1 & Cell 2 &  \rotatebox{-90}{External}\\
  \cline{2-3}    & Cell 3 & Cell 4 & \\
  \cline{2-3}
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Human/organizational/social systems} 
\end{tabular}
```

Is somebody able to help? 
Tanks a lot

Comment: Welcome into the group of the users of TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `origin=c` added as an option ot `\rotatebox` two additional empty lines per row and `\multirow{4}`commands:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tabular}{c|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|c}
   \multicolumn{4}{c}{Technical/economic systems} \\
     \cline{2-3}
     \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Internal}} &
     Cell 1 & Cell 2 &  \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{External}}\\
     & & & \\
     \cline{2-3}    & Cell 3 & Cell 4 & \\
     & & & \\
     \cline{2-3}
     \multicolumn{4}{c}{Human/organizational/social systems} 
     \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```